# Android: Adding a back button without starting a new activity

Tags: java, android, back

I am new to android and just had a simple question. In an app I am making, I have a back button to go back to the previous activity. However, it just creates a new activity of the activity that was opened before it. I don't want the user to have to click the actual back button, but I want the button I create to have the same code (where it destroys the current activity and goes back to the previous one). Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Calling `finish` when the button is clicked should work as you expect. Android manages the `Activity` stacks. If your's is the first in a stack, it will not know explicitly where "back" goes. But if it finishes, Android knows where the user was previous to launching your `Activity` and will do the work for you.

By the way, this includes your own activities. In other words, to go to a previous activity, including your own, just call `finish` - the main thing here is to remember to save important data, get rid of no-longer-needed objects and object references, etc. In other words, clean up your mess before you leave.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `finish()` on your button press:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

[Activity#finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) would close the current activity and return the user to the activity that opened it.

Answer (score 0):

The best was is to create a `savedInstanceState` on Pause. Then `onResume()` you just have to call the `savedInstanceState`, and the activity will resume just the way you left it.